# Pattern puzzle 013

Tags: pattern

Find the missing cells in the image below.

[image: pattern_finding_iucyos]

I tried to find, but couldn't.

> I got help from one person who said that there is a similarity in 2nd and 3rd row from 2nd column to 5th column, so the similarity should continue below in 4th and 5th rows in corresponding columns. However, I still can't find the last row.

Source: This question was asked in IU Cerrahpasa exam for int'l students this year, 2020. They shared the questions in their website, the exam is already over. I have discussed about these types of exams in my earlier posts.

> Now the question has an answer, although drawn a bit incorrect, I think I can post the potential options and the correct answer here. Thanks for @Deepthinker101 especially for the efforts.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question looks like suduku but it has different rules.

There are 3 columns and 3 rows which contains 2x2 cells of shapes.

Each column follows different rule of a certain movement (the movement of cells showed in different rows on same column).

In the left column all shapes move anti clockwise.
In the middle all the shapes from the top two cells go to the bottom and vice versa.

In the right all the shapes move in a clockwise direction.

Here is a small example.
Let say this is the data is in the left column:

1 | 2 
3 | 4

Then the next row it this column will look like:

2 | 4
1 | 3

Then the answer is:
[image](https://ibb.co/k0VWWf7)

Big thanks to @Deepthinker101 helping with editing the answer

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I didn't understand your solution clearly. Can you elaborate it more, please? Thanks.

Comment: @garakchy I added it a bit

Comment: Edited haha ( not added )

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying it is just horribly put

Comment: There are 3 columns which contains 3 4 cells of shapes. Each column follows different rule of a certain movement from the top 4 celled pattern to the one below it. In the left column all shapes move anti clockwise. In the middle all the shapes from the top two cells go to the bottom and vice versa. In the right all the shapes move in a clockwise direction.

Comment: @Deepthinker may I copy your paragraph?

Comment: Sure man you can do it

Comment: This puzzle was pretty obvious

Comment: I lik the question, a specially because the small amount of shapes the problem has and the width of the lines are great help.

Comment: I found the puzzle was made worse by the fact that shapes that are supposed to be the same are sometimes drawn slightly differently, and their positions within the cells are slightly different too, leading one to wonder if these are intentional or not.